# Backtrack 5 R3 - Refuses to connect to VPN

Tags: vpn

I wanted to ask this on the Backtrack Linux forums but for some reason I couldn't register, reading it was disabled by the administrator. So I apologize if I'm in the wrong place (which I feel like I am, even though BT is based on Ubuntu).

A week ago my VPN connections were fine. I'm using network-manager on GNOME. My OpenVPN connections (done via terminal) also connected fine. Now, out of nowhere, the PPTP VPN setup in my network-manager keep reporting a failed connection, and when I try OpenVPN it reports a success, but I can't access the internet. If I enter in a site it just hangs forever :(

The same VPN with same config, same credentials, same everything works perfectly on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 7 (I have a triple boot). I did not run any updates or upgrades since then. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The first place I'd look for clues would be the openvpn log, which is often sent to syslog. That may give you some clues (possibly failures to create routes, or a disconnection for some reason after the client is executed).

If there are no obvious signs of issues in the logs, next would be the routes it creates.
Use `ip route show` and see if the correct networks are being added to the route table and that they are pointing at the tun/tap device that OpenVPN is creating. If they look correct and `ip route get x.x.x.x` (where `x.x.x.x` is an IP on the VPN network) shows the correct route, next would be firewalls.

If you are using `iptables` do you have a rules for the `OUTPUT` and/or `FORWARD` chains to allow traffic out through the tun/tap device, and to the networks you are trying to reach. On trying to connect to a host does `tcpdump` show any signs of the traffic being routed over the VPN?

You also mention "entering a site", is that on your broswer? If so, what does `dig <domain>` show for its results? (Where `<domain>` is the DNS domain you are trying to reach via your browser, for example `dig www.google.com`. It may be that your client is being pushed a set of nameserver to put in resolv.conf that can't be reached via your VPN, and then DNS is failing.